# docker images select by tag with NOT logic

Tags: docker

In my environment, there are:

```
REPOSITORY                      TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED      SIZE
xxxxx.azurecr.io/test-api   latest    249d55325q68   2 days ago   103MB
xxxxx.azurecr.io/test-api   v01       249d55325q68   2 days ago   103MB
xxxxx.azurecr.io/test-api   b03       249d55325q68   2 days ago   103MB
```

I want the result which do not have TAG 'latest'

When I input this:
docker images xxxxx.azurecr.io/test-api:latest

I got:

```
xxxxx.azurecr.io/test-api   latest    249d55325q68   2 days ago   103MB
```

**What shall I do if I want this result?**

```
xxxxx.azurecr.io/test-api   v01       249d55325q68   2 days ago   103MB
xxxxx.azurecr.io/test-api   b03       249d55325q68   2 days ago   103MB
```

I tried --filter and but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest option is to `grep` the output and invert the match (`-v` flag):

```
docker image list|grep -v latest
```

This will give you the desired output:

```
REPOSITORY                      TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED      SIZE
xxxxx.azurecr.io/test-api   v01       249d55325q68   2 days ago   103MB
xxxxx.azurecr.io/test-api   b03       249d55325q68   2 days ago   103MB
```

This will not work properly if a line in the output contains the word 'latest' in any place other than the tag.